# Windows phone 7 3d game development

Tags: windows-phone-7, 3d, game-engine

i am looking out for any IDE/tool/game engine for development of 3d game in windows phone 7, something like Unity3d ? please help on few.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone 7 doen't support native code so there isn't a lot of tools/engines ported to it (that may change in Windows Phone 8). The best approach to develop an 3D game on WP7 is use Microsoft XNA 4.